# Streaming MP4 problem - obvious answer?

Tags: android, streaming, mp4, android-videoview

I'm a Flash developer by trade, have recently made the jump into Android as the company I work for are moving into apps. I've made a video gallery based on an XML feed, it all works fine until I have to play the movie itself, at which point I get:

Unable to play video. Invalid streaming data.

My gallery items fire up another activity with the .mp4 link as an extra:

```
public class Video_play extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

String vLink;
Uri vid;
VideoView vv;
MediaPlayer mp;
SurfaceHolder holder;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);//Hide app title

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

    if (extras != null) {
        vLink = extras.getString("video");
        vid = Uri.parse(vLink);
    }

    setContentView(R.layout.vidplay_layout);

    vv = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.vid_fscreen);
    Log.i("Video link is: ",vid+"");
    MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
    mediaController.setAnchorView(vv);
    vv.setMediaController(mediaController);
    vv.setVideoURI(vid);
    vv.start();

}


public void onClick(View v) {



}



}
```

I've been looking all afternoon and I can't find any straightforward advice on what I'm doing wrong. Any help would be absolutely life-saving, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

What version of Android are you testing it on? HTTP progressive streaming for MP4 video was not fully supported until Android 2.2.

For streaming playback on earlier Android versions you can usually work around this by using post-encoding software like MP4Box to add "hint tracks" to the file:

```
MP4Box -hint <filename>
```

http://www.videohelp.com/tools/mp4box

Comment: I'm using 2.2, none of our builds will be using anything earlier than this. Sorry, it seems like such an obvious one but can't find a good way to do it!

Again, chees in advance

Comment: I can confirm that using MP4Box on a baseline encoded H.264 video has fixed a number of device specific playback issues. Thanks for the tip!